# Storing an SQL value as a PHP variable ("Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int")

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

At the moment, I'm trying to store a value from a MySQL table as a variable in PHP, so running some basic tests to make sure that I can access the variable.
I've managed to store the varaible, which will either be a 1 or a 0 (1 = server is up and running, 0 = server down).

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*****";
$dbname = "scicomservers";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT nccpm FROM web_servers WHERE time_checked='2016-02-16 11:44:17.212126'";
$nccpm = $conn->query($sql);

    if($nccpm==1){
      echo("NCCPM Server is running");
    }

$conn->close();
?>
```

When I run this code, it reads in that $nccpm is 1, and it echos the statement, however, I get the error:

> Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SciCom_admin_servers/files/connect2.php
>   on line 17

Line 17 being the if statement: "*if($nccpm==1){*".

I've had a look around on here, and I think this may be because it is trying to print an array of the answers, however it will only ever be one value that I will retrieve. The column of the DB is an int.

I was wondering, what would be a better way of coding this? It clearly isn't the best practice!

Thank you very much.

Comment: fetch the results from the query first

Comment: You still have to fetch the value or you can use [num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: How would I fetch the value? I've tried num_rows but I get a fatal error

Answer (score 4):

```
$sql = "SELECT nccpm FROM web_servers WHERE time_checked='2016-02-16 11:44:17.212126'";
$ncc = $conn->query($sql);
$nccpm = $conn->fetch_array($ncc);
if ($nccpm['nccpm'] == 1)
{
 // Rest of  script
 }
```

You need to fetch your query or find how many rows are returned

Comment: When using that code, I get the error message: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::num_rows() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SciCom_admin_servers/files/connect2.php on line 16`

Comment: Change $conn->num_rows($ncc); To $ncc->num_rows(); and try that

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows() in [file path] on line 16` line 16 being $nccpm = $ncc->num_rows();

Comment: Change query to $sql = "SELECT COUNT(nccpm) FROM web_servers WHERE time_checked='2016-02-16 11:44:17.212126'";

Comment: `Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int ` just to clarify - I don't want to check whether 1 result is given, I want to check if the result value is '1'

Comment: Cheers! And hmm still getting `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_array()`

Comment: Change $nccpm = $conn->fetch_array($ncc); to $nccpm = $ncc->fetch_array;  or $nccpm = $ncc->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: nccpm in [file path] on line 18` where line 18 is `if ($nccpm['nccpm'] == 1)` ... really baffled here